# Cannot access internal directory created

Tags: java, android

When I try to create a directory in storage/emulator/0/ directory, it becomes invisible and inaccessible. I use `mkdir()` to create, and when I check its existence, `dir.exists()` returns true, even though I cannot access it.

My device runs in API 23, so I get the permissions in runtime, like this:

```
 boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermission) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_READ_STORAGE);
    }
```

I also create `onRequestPermissionsResult` function:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_READ_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //reload my activity with permission granted or use the features what required the permission
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this function, I try to access my directory

```
 public void makeOutSide(String song, InputStream ins){

    // Create the directory

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"appMemes");
    // If it does not exists, make it.
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs(); // Generating the directory
    }
    try {
        // Open the resource
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ins.available()];
        ins.read(buffer);
        ins.close();
        // Burn
        String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/appMemes/"+song+".mp3";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
}
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.renan.appmemes">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application


...
</application>
```

Comment: How did you tried to access it ?

Comment: I update my question, man

Comment: `dir.mkdirs(); `. It might fail. And it does, isnt it!? It should be: `if(!dir.mkdirs()){Toast(.......); return;}`.

Comment: `String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/appMemes/"+song+".mp3";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);`. Pretty bad coding to construct that path yet again. Now there is twice "/appMemes" in your code. No good. Replace by `File file = new File(dir, song+".mp3"); FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);`.

Comment: `directory in storage/emulator/0/ directory, it becomes invisible and inaccessible. `. You mean `/storage/emulator/0/` !? And what do you mean with invisible? For whom? Where? And what do you mean with inaccessible? By whom? Where? How?

Comment: I use debug to see this, and directory has created without error. But cannot be acess

Comment: My directory `storage/emulator/0/appMemes` return true  when `dir.exists()` like it were created when I first ran the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first put EnableRuntimePermission Function in Oncreate

```
private void EnableRuntimePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
               != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                    (MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Allow permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(
                            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RequestPermissionCode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case RequestPermissionCode:

                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean writeExternalFile = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (writeExternalFile) {
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Allow permissions to Edit the Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

then create direcory using this line

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DSLR CAMERASagar/");
        dir.mkdirs();
```

Comment: Hello ! I do exactly what you said , but same error persists. Here I pasted my function onCreate()  and the function where I try create and acess directory : https://pastebin.com/ce5WgVF6

Comment: no error message appears, but when I try to access a file that saved in the directory folder I created, it is not there. I also can not see the directory I created, even though verification indicates that it is...

Comment: i think you need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: put my EnableRuntimePermission function in your Oncreate method